# CDN - How to compress JS file

Tags: php, .htaccess, compression, gzip

I wondering how jquery CDN can make its file send with lightweight size. But if i copy it or download the code to my computer and access it locally, The file become bigger.

#### Story 1

Then i try to compress the code with `.htaccess` and browser outputing error page that say 'Content-encoding error', emm okay next i will try another way

#### Story 2

I don't give up at story 1, so i searching for solutions for my problem, and i using PHP

```
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
```

But the script above give the same error like Story 1.

### Question

So the question, How to compressing JS file with PHP or .`htaccess`, maybe you have a smart idea. Please help me all ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe by using the Apache `mod_deflate` module, which allow you to compress file before sent to the client

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html

Comment: Ok. sorry... But as you trying to compress from htacess (story 1) with gzip (gzip format) or deflate (zlib format) ? Maybe Gzip is more reliable to avoir content encoding error ...

Comment: Thanks i'm looking at the server-side and found is mod_deflate deactived. Thanks friend ...